# Getting specific element value with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am automating shopping site, where at last I want to print the total bill. I have tried the following code but error shown that no such attribute is known.  Code here is here:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="price-overview"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/dl/dd')
                                
                                    
 price_value = price.getAttribute("US $");
 print("The total price is: "+ str(price_value));
`  [![highlighted in image too][1]][1]
```

[image: image is here]

Comment: "but didn't work" is not a helpful description of what happened.

Comment: error shown that no such attribute is known

Comment: Can you share the url or html

Comment: So why would you think that an HTML element would have an attribute with the name `"US $"`? As another user said, post a snippet of the HTML tags.

Comment: `get_attribute()` not `getAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `price.getAttribute("US $");` you should use `price.getText()` since it's just a text there.
Also, there no need to put `;` at the end of the commands. It's Python, not Java :)

Answer (score 0):

To get an attribute in Python, use `get_attribute()` not `getAttribute`.
If there is really such attribute, it should solve your question.

Another approach you can try: Find the correct locator and add to it `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`.

Such locator does not seem to be correct: `//*[@id="price-overview"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/dl/dd`. It is not stable, has high probability to be changed.

Use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('short xpath').text` to the text from an element.